# removeClass method not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a main div container with 4 hidden divs inside it (I created a class in css with display:none, and added it to each of the inner divs) , the main div reads a value from a dropdown list and according to the read value unhides that many divs.

```
 <div id="ddlContainer">
            <div id="div1" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl1">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="div2" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl2">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="div3" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl3">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="div4" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl4">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the removeClass isn't working for me.

```
  var diff, NumofHiddenDDLs = $("#ddlContainer").children().filter("[class=hide]");
        if (ReadValue > NumofHiddenDDLs.length) {
            diff = 1;
        }
        else {
            diff = 2;
        }
        if (diff == 1) {
            //TODO add class hide to shown divs
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < ReadValue; i++) 
                ($("#ddlContainer").children()[i]).removeClass("hide");
        }
```

Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Just use `var diff = $('#ddlContainer > .hide').length; if (diff === 1) { TODO } else { $('#ddlContainer > .hide').removeClass('hide') }`

Answer (score 6):

You need an extra `$`:

```
$($("#ddlContainer").children()[i]).removeClass("hide");
```

This `$("#ddlContainer").children()[i]` will return the i-th children of the element with id `ddlContainer`, which would would be an html element and not a jQuery object. So you want have access to the jQuery methods. By wrapping this with a `$` you will have a jQuery object and you will have access to the `removeClass` method.

Another way of achieving the same result is to make use `Satpal` answer, in which instead of accessing the array of children with an index to make use of the `eq` method and to get a jQuery object that would contain the element you want.

Comment: **Why?**. First getting DOM element and then wrapping again in jQuery. Just use `$('#ddlContainer').children().eq(i).removeClass('hide');` as in other answer.

Comment: @Tushar You are bloody right. However, I tried to point out what's the minimal change that is needed. I will include also this in my answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Problem with your implementation is that `($("#ddlContainer").children()[i])` returns DOM element and they don't have `removeClass()` method.

You should use `.eq(index)` to get the desired element then use `removeClass()`

```
$("#ddlContainer").children().eq(i).removeClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `lt` selector and remove for loop -

```
$("#ddlContainer").children(":lt(" + ReadValue + ")").removeClass("hide");
```

Check out below demo version where I have hide CSS class (with background-color RED) and removing it for index less than 3 -

```js
$(function(){
  $("#ddlContainer").children(":lt(3)").removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
 background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ddlContainer">
            <div id="div1" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl1">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="div2" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl2">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="div3" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl3">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="div4" class="hide">
                <center>Select option:</center>
                <select id="ddl4">
                      <!--options are added here-->
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have i-th element, simply use pure js functionality classList

`$("#ddlContainer").children()[i].classList.remove("hide")`

Notice: by this scenario, you won't create additional object in in each step